# Can jOOQ be used to check native SQL string

Tags: java, sql, native, jooq

I want to integrate jOOQ in a project which uses native SQL and `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate`. The database schema  changes often and developers have to search the code for a column that has been removed and update the queries. Hibernate or another ORM solution isn't an option as queries are sometimes very large and developers get them and just have to insert into the application code. This is very error-prune. So I thought to integrate jOOQ but gradually.

Can jOOQ throw compile time errors if a native SQL cannot be executed?

I've tried the following:

```
// Existing code
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = ...
    
    String sql = "select ...";
    
// Check code
    try {
            DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection());
            Query query = dslContext.parser().parseQuery(sql + " order by NON_EXISTING_COLUMN");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        ...
    }
    
// Existing code
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, ...)
```

But it compiles well although `NON_EXISTING_COLUMN` doesn't really exist. Maybe I know the jOOQ API not very well yet. But I thought that it should be capable of doing it. The table classes are generated, so it can check whether the query which is build from a native SQL string is executable without executing it. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

why don't use generated class files rather than typing native SQL?

`dslContext.selectFrom(GENERATED_TABLE)...`

PS: If you use JOOQ DSL(with generated classes) for generating SQL it would be work but not completely in some cases if you do mistakes even on generated classes (relations or some aggregate functions) it will not complain about it and will compile successfully.

Comment: I've explained it partially already. Developers get native SQL from others and insert it into the application code. There is already a lot of native SQL in the application code and not enough time to rewrite it using jOOQ. So I thought as the first step to use it at least as a query validation tool. And maybe later do a complete switch to jOOQ.

Comment: Ok. Firstly, hope you will find the answer. In any case, your team can convert it step by step and write test cases for each SQL query and validating SQL queries by mock objects.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of jOOQ did not implement meta data lookups in the parser, or only to some limited extent, and just accepted all valid identifiers. Starting with jOOQ 3.14, there will be an improved implementation as of:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9061

You will need to provide jOOQ with a [`Configuration.metaProvider()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Configuration.html#metaProvider()) (it defaults to the JDBC `DatabaseMetaData` backed implementation. You might prefer using generated code), and then jOOQ will try to resolve all identifiers.

Prior to jOOQ 3.14, you could implement a `VisitListener` which traverses the parsed SQL query, and validate all the identifiers yourself.